# How to use timeout in dockerfile with alpine base?

Tags: docker, timeout, alpine-linux

## Context

I'm writing a dockerfile where I run a server application based on `alpine:3.9` docker image. I test if my application is correctly installed by running it and sending a `GET` request with `curl`.

I send requests until I get an answer. So in case of trouble I want to timeout my tests using the built-in `timeout` function.

## Pre-requirements

I'm using docker `version 19.03.4, build 9013bf583a` on debian.

## Problem

The command:

```sh
docker run --rm -it alpine:3.9 timeout -t 2 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 5; echo "Not to be seen..."'
```

Exit displaying `Not to be seen...`.

If I use timeout this way, the timeout seems to be ignored... I got the same problem if I put this in a docker file.

```
FROM alpine:3.9
RUN timeout -t 2 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 5; echo "Not to be seen..."'
```

```
docker build -t test .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:3.9
 ---> 055936d39205
Step 2/2 : RUN timeout -t 2 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 5; echo "Not to be seen..."'
 ---> Running in 0fa22cd02173
Not to be seen...
Removing intermediate container 0fa22cd02173
 ---> e88107c3811b
Successfully built e88107c3811b
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

We can see the `Not to be seen...` displayed in console.

How to solve this issue ?

## Reflexions / Tests

I test multiple things and the timeout function works well. It should be a problem when using it in dockerfile or passing it in `docker run` function...

---

When I try:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine:3.9 /bin/sh
# Then in container
timeout -t 2 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 5; echo "Not to be seen..."'
```

Exit with status code 143. And display `Terminated`.

---

When I try:

```
docker run --rm --name test -td alpine:3.9 /bin/sh
docker exec -it test timeout -t 2 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 5; echo "Not to be seen..."'
```

Exit with status code 143. Nothing displayed as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many programs drop default signal handlers when running as PID 1 (including `/bin/sh`).

You need to use the `--init` flag in order to make the container exit properly:

> --init                           Run an init inside the container that forwards signals and reaps processes

This should work:

`docker run --rm -it --init alpine:3.9 timeout -t 2 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 5; echo "Not to be seen..."'`

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for my late answer. The solution works well when using `docker run` command but not for building a Dockerfile. Is there a solution for using timeout in Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 1):

In a dockerfile context, pb can be solve using `https://github.com/krallin/tini` tool.

Using following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk add --no-cache tini
RUN /sbin/tini timeout -t 2 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 5; echo "Not to be seen..."'
```

Executing `docker build .`

Result

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.9
 ---> 055936d39205
Step 2/3 : RUN apk add --no-cache tini
 ---> Running in 018e342caa67
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing tini (0.18.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 6 MiB in 15 packages
Removing intermediate container 018e342caa67
 ---> 915c3d5dc7fe
Step 3/3 : RUN /sbin/tini timeout -t 2 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 5; echo "Not to be seen..."'
 ---> Running in 3852a4f6a43d
The command '/bin/sh -c /sbin/tini timeout -t 2 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 5; echo "Not to be seen..."'' returned a non-zero code: 143
```

As seen the build has stoped with code 143.

The solution impose using external tool. Feel free to propose, if there is a more straight away solution.

PS: Thanks to  @Eduardo Baitello for setting me on the right path :)

Answer (score 0):

Timeout option in Dockerfile, you can embed `timeout <value>` directly for commands in Dockerfile

Eg:

````
ARG GOLANG=golang:1.16.4-alpine3.12
FROM ${GOLANG}
RUN timeout 60 curl -sL https://install.goreleaser.com/github.com/golangci/golangci-lint.sh```
````